# PHP: Class containing array of sponsors and method for echoing them

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

I want to have my Datasource_Sponsor class contain sponsor information, an array called sponsorList and a method which echoes each sponsor.

At the moment I have this

```
class Datasource_Sponsor
 {

protected $sponsor = 'New and Upcoming Startup';
protected $sponsor2 = 'Average Company Ltd.';
protected $sponsor3 = 'Super Duper Cool Best Company Ever';


protected $sponsorList = array($sponsor, $sponsor2, $sponsor3);

public function returnSponsors()
{
    foreach ($sponsorList as $sponsor) {
        $sponsor = new Sponsor();
        echo 'Sponsor: ' . $sponsor->getSponsor() . '<br/>';
        echo '<hr>';
        }

    }
}
```

And I get this error "Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations" for this line

```
protected $sponsorList = array($sponsor, $sponsor2, $sponsor3);
```

Comment: `new Sponsor` shouldn't that be `new Datasource_Sponsor`?

Comment: Have another file 'sponsor.php'

Comment: you may need to extend it then.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use properties in that way, i suggest you to do this:

```
<?php
class Datasource_Sponsor
 {

    protected $sponsor = 'New and Upcoming Startup';
    protected $sponsor2 = 'Average Company Ltd.';
    protected $sponsor3 = 'Super Duper Cool Best Company Ever';

    protected $sponsorList;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->sponsorList = [$this->sponsor, $this->sponsor2, $this->sponsor3];
    }

    public function returnSponsors()
    {
        foreach ($this->sponsorList as $sponsor) {
            $myOthersponsor = new Sponsor();
            echo 'Sponsor: ' . $myOthersponsor->getSponsor() . '<br/>';
            echo '<hr>';
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks better. Still doesn't work unfortunately.

foreach ($this->sponsorList as $sponsor)

On this line, $sponsor doesn't seem to be recognised

Comment: Yes, because you are making quite a mess (no offense), you are using ```$sponsor``` for the foreach and overriding it 1 line later, caling a new class ```sponsor```, plus i don't get why you need to use a separated class to do the same thing, i'll edit my reply to remove overriding